# IntelliJ IDEA code format from checkstyle configuration

Tags: intellij-idea, code-formatting, checkstyle

I've decided to contribute to android maven plugin.

They use quite specific code style format. It will take some time for me to modify IDEA code format rules to satisfy their requirements.

Fortunately there is checkstyle configuration. I've already installed check-style plugin for IDEA and immediately see where my current formatting is wrong.

Unfortunately I didn't find way to import checkstyle configuration into IDEA formatting rules.

I'm interested if it's possible.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**UPDATE**: supported since 4.24.0 plug-in version, [see here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-61520#comment=27-1292600) for details.

---

Original answer from 2013:

[Not possible yet](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-61520), please star/vote to track the progress of the issue.

[Plugin On GitHub](https://github.com/jshiell/checkstyle-idea)

[How to set it up](https://checkstyle-addons.thomasjensen.com/run.html#run-intellij)

[image: install pluging]

[image: Example of how it looks like in intellij]

Comment: Sad :( What is common way to share code formatting across the team? I saw post about some file from ./idea folder. But I usually avoid to commit ide specific files to repositories

Comment: `.idea/codeStyleSettings.xml`, see the [FAQ](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/docs/DOC-1186).

Answer (score 76):

finally there is something:

checkstyle-IDEA since 4.24.0 features import of checkstyle config.

> A solution is available now:
>
> 1. Please install CheckStyle-IDEA plugin (http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/1065?pr=idea), it can be found via plug-in repository (Settings|Plugins|Browse repositories).
> 2. Go to Settings|Editor|Code Style, choose a code style you want to import CheckStyle configuration to.
> 3. Click Manage...|Import.., choose "CheckStyle Configuration" and select a corresponding CheckStyle configuration file. Click OK.
>
> At the end you will see a message "CheckStyle configuration settings were imported to ... scheme".
>
> If you encounter any problems, you can create a new issue for the CheckStyle plug-in here: https://github.com/jshiell/checkstyle-idea/issues. This issue is actually a duplicate of https://github.com/jshiell/checkstyle-idea/issues/126.
>
> CheckStyle plug-in version where the feature is available is 4.24.0

Copied from 
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-61520#comment=27-1292600

Comment: Yay! I will try! Thanks for sharing!

Comment: Is it possible wise verse? Export it to checkstyle from idea settings?

Comment: This appears to still not be a solution to the question to configure _formatting_ using CheckStyle rules.

Comment: @SanderVerhagen it is, actually. Once you imported the config, make sure that is is being applied to the project, and then do a `ctrl-shift-alt-L` to format the current file...

Comment: Is it possible to export the Idea code style as a `checkstyle.xml`?

Comment: @SanderVerhagen if you also install the Save Actions plugin and configure it to reformat the file on save then it'll for automatically on save

Answer (score 6):

There is an ugly workaround that I have been able to live with:

First import the Checkstyle format into Eclipse, as explained here: 
  [How to generate an Eclipse formatter configuration from a checkstyle configuration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/984778/how-to-generate-an-eclipse-formatter-configuration-from-a-checkstyle-configurati)

Then export the format from Eclipse (via Windows --> Preferences --> Java --> Code Style --> Formatter -> Edit -> Export  and import the resulting *.xml file into IntelliJ IDEA

Of course this is kinda bonkers especially if you do not have someone around who has Eclipse running anyway, as you have to install it just to be able to "translate" the checkstyle format into something IntelliJ can read; but if it only has to be done once per project it might be somewhat better than manually adjust the format.

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me.

1. Go to Preferences > Editor > Code Style > Java
2. In the `Scheme` dropdown, import your desired `checkstyle.xml`[image: import-cecktyle-scheme]
3. Intellij calls the newly imported scheme as `Default copy`
4. Use the `Rename` option to choose any other name. [image]

Answer (score 1):

Just ran `mvn spotless:apply` as suggested by Intellij. This helped me auto resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me is using [Adapter for Eclipse Code Formatter](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6546-adapter-for-eclipse-code-formatter)
. IntelliJ IDEA 2022.3.1

1. Install it using `Settings -> Plugins -> Adapter for Eclipse Code Formatter`
2. After restart, `Settings -> Adapter for Eclipse Code Formatter`

   - `Use Eclipse's Code Formatter`
   - `Eclipse formatter config -> Eclipse workspace/project folder or config file`