# How fix all check style issues with Intellij Idea?

Tags: maven, plugins, intellij-idea, checkstyle

I have an xml configuration file for maven checkstyle plugin. I have installed Intellij Idea plugin and see all checkstyle violation. Is there a way to fix most of them automatically? For example auto formatting setting? Is there a way to setup Intellij Idea to autoformat from checktyle config file?

Comment: If you have custom/added code-style in settings, then on file if you hit 'Ctrl+Alt+L' will reformat the code

Answer (score 9):

There is an option now.

checkstyle-IDEA since 4.24.0 features import of checkstyle config.

> Please install CheckStyle-IDEA plugin
> (http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/1065?pr=idea), it can be found
> via plug-in repository (Settings|Plugins|Browse repositories). Go to
> Settings|Editor|Code Style, choose a code style you want to import
> CheckStyle configuration to. Click on the gear, then 'import scheme', choose
> "CheckStyle Configuration" and select a corresponding CheckStyle
> configuration file. Click OK. At the end you will see a message
> "CheckStyle configuration settings were imported to ... scheme".
>
> If you encounter any problems, you can create a new issue for the
> CheckStyle plug-in here:
> https://github.com/jshiell/checkstyle-idea/issues. This issue is
> actually a duplicate of
> https://github.com/jshiell/checkstyle-idea/issues/126.
>
> CheckStyle plug-in version where the feature is available is 4.24.0

Copied from https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-61520#comment=27-1292600. Copied the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35273850/501785)

Edit: Quote has been changed for clarity and to meet the current UI design.

Comment: Note - this wasn't working for me, and I was about ready to write up a bug report, and then I noticed that I have a local .editorconfig file. It turned out the .editorconfig file supersedes the other editor settings. Specifically my .editorconfig file specified an indent_size = 4, but google's checkstyle xml specifies 2. Once I commented out the line in my .editorconfig, the auto-format worked.

Comment: How does importing an existing xml enable autofixing the issues?

Comment: @AdamWise so true.. I was troubled with this file for a while and the issue is that 4 spaces and 2 spaces indent. Thanks

Comment: I am not able to see the Manage button

Comment: this doesn't answer the question - they were asking about autofixing which apparently Eclipse can do

Answer (score 5):

I have the same problem. As far as I know, the rules used for reformatting cannot be imported from Checkstyle config. You can configure your Checkstyle rules in the Idea's Code Style config `(File -> Settings -> Code Style)` and then reformat the code `(Code -> Reformat Code [Ctrl+Alt+L])` according to the rules (you can apply it to the whole code base at once).

Answer (score 4):

1. import your code style config first
   [image]
2. reformat your code.