# Intelij auto fix gradlew checkstyle errors like formatting?

Tags: intellij-idea

I am trying to auto fix my gradle checkstyle errors instead of manually fixing each individual one. I have installed the checkstyle plugin: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/1065-checkstyle-idea 
and I am trying to follow these steps: [How fix all check style issues with Intellij Idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19952500/how-fix-all-check-style-issues-with-intellij-idea)
but it doesn't seem to be working as when i press ctrl + alt + l, my code gets formatted but the checkstyle errors do not get fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to get the **Reformat Code** dialog where you can enable the **Code cleanup** option:

[image: cleanup]

Comment: Nothing seems to happen... When I perform this action and then re-run the CheckStyle-IDEA scan, all warnings are still present.

Comment: @rocksNwaves This is for built-in IntelliJ IDEA functionality. CheckStyle-IDEA is a third-party plug-in and may work differently.

Comment: Ah, interesting! Is the IntelliJ IDEA built in checkstyle configurable? Can I point it to an XML file, then delete the CheckStyle-IDEA plugin?

Comment: @rocksNwaves Yes, see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/code-inspection.html.

Comment: Hmm. Following that page, I found the "Code Style issues" inspection. I see that I can select or unselect what I want it to look for, but no way to point it to an XML file. 

I have a Maven checkstyle plugin being run when I build. It has an associated checkstyle xml file. I want to point IntelliJ at this file so that Intellij can correct my formatting errors.