# Is it possible to define a code style in checkstyle based on a code style from IntelliJ idea?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, coding-style

I have a project which I'm developing in IntelliJ Idea and I have formatting rules like where curly braces are to be located and so on. Is it possible to convert an IntelliJ code style into a checkstyle one so that when I run reports through Maven, I don't see warnings like "Right curly brace and next "else", "catch" and "finally" keywords should be located on the same line"...?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I asked question if it is possible to import checkstyle rules as formatting rules for IDEA. And I got answer it is not possible

Comment: Who did you ask and where?

Comment: It is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14539313/intellij-idea-code-format-from-checkstyle-configuration

Comment: Thanks! I guess I'll need to wait for that to be resolved and find a workaround in the meantime... :-|

Answer (score 0):

Answer for your question is a maven-checkstyle-plugin.

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/

But before using, you need to understand that maven is a separate application is not fully integrated with the idea. ie this plugin will not use the idea of ​​setting, but it will have to use a separate files configuration.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I am well aware of the fact that they are two separate tools. One is an IDE while the other is a build tool. However, I was hoping I could get the code style from Idea converted to a rule set for Checkstyle.