# How to import Checkstyle rules from XML file in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, checkstyle

I know there is QAPlug - Checkstyle and I'm trying to use it.

In menu Project *Settings* -> *QAPlug* -> *Checkstyle* I set *Xml configuration file* and *Jar file* as well. Then when *Check loaded rules* button is pressed such a message pops up:

[image]

That's very kind of this plugin it has found rules in XML file. Why isn't it loading them though?

Checkstyle configuration file I'm using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Puppy Crawl//DTD Check Configuration 1.3//EN" "http://www.puppycrawl.com/dtds/configuration_1_3.dtd">

<module name="Checker">
    <property name="severity" value="error"/>
    <module name="TreeWalker">
        <property name="cacheFile" value="build/checkstyle.cache"/>
        <module name="FileContentsHolder"/>
        <module name="RegexpSinglelineJava">
            <property name="format" value="\s+$"/>
            <property name="message" value="Line has trailing spaces."/>
            <property name="ignoreComments" value="true"/>
        </module>
        <module name="RegexpSinglelineJava">
            <property name="format" value="^\t* +\t*\S"/>
            <property name="message"
                value="Line has leading space characters; indentation should be performed with tabs only."/>
            <property name="ignoreComments" value="true"/>
        </module>
        <module name="ConstantName"/>
        <module name="LocalFinalVariableName"/>
        <module name="LocalVariableName"/>
        <module name="MemberName"/>
        <module name="MethodName"/>
        <module name="PackageName"/>
        <module name="ParameterName"/>
        <module name="StaticVariableName"/>
        <module name="TypeName"/>
        <module name="AvoidStarImport"/>
        <module name="IllegalImport">
            <property name="illegalPkgs" value="sun, junit.framework, org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers"/>
        </module>
        <module name="RedundantImport"/>
        <module name="UnusedImports"/>
        <module name="ImportOrder">
            <property name="groups" value="/^((?!java).)*$/,/javax\./,/java\./"/>
            <property name="ordered" value="true"/>
            <property name="separated" value="false"/>
            <property name="option" value="bottom"/>
        </module>
        <module name="ParameterAssignment"/>
        <module name="LineLength">
            <property name="max" value="180"/>
            <property name="tabWidth" value="1"/>
            <property name="ignorePattern" value="(^import)|(\s*@ScenarioReference)|(\s*@ScenarioDescription)|(\s*title)|(\s*story)|(\s*@Given)|(\s*@When)|(\s*@Then)|(\s*@Alias)"/>
        </module>
        <module name="MethodLength"/>
        <module name="ParameterNumber">
            <property name="max" value="8"/>
        </module>
        <module name="EmptyForIteratorPad"/>
        <module name="MethodParamPad"/>
        <module name="NoWhitespaceAfter">
            <property name="tokens"
                value="BNOT,DEC,DOT,INC,LNOT,UNARY_MINUS,UNARY_PLUS"/>
        </module>
        <module name="NoWhitespaceBefore"/>
        <module name="OperatorWrap"/>
        <module name="ParenPad"/>
        <module name="TypecastParenPad"/>
        <module name="WhitespaceAfter"/>

        <!--Please be aware of this bug: http://sourceforge.net/p/checkstyle/bugs/593/-->
        <!--[checkstyle-bugs-593] WhitespaceAround wrongly targets annotation element arrays-->
        <module name="WhitespaceAround">
            <property name="allowEmptyConstructors" value="true" />
        </module>

        <module name="ModifierOrder"/>
        <module name="RedundantModifier"/>
        <module name="AvoidNestedBlocks"/>
        <module name="EmptyBlock"/>
        <module name="LeftCurly"/>
        <module name="NeedBraces"/>
        <module name="RightCurly"/>
        <module name="EmptyStatement"/>
        <module name="EqualsHashCode"/>
        <module name="IllegalInstantiation"/>
        <module name="InnerAssignment"/>
        <module name="MagicNumber">
            <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
            <property name="ignoreNumbers" value="-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, -4"/>
        </module>
        <module name="MissingSwitchDefault"/>
        <module name="RedundantThrows"/>
        <module name="SimplifyBooleanExpression"/>
        <module name="SimplifyBooleanReturn"/>
        <module name="FinalClass"/>
        <module name="InterfaceIsType"/>
        <module name="VisibilityModifier">
            <property name="packageAllowed" value="true"/>
            <property name="protectedAllowed" value="true"/>
            <property name="publicMemberPattern" value="^expectedException$|^temporaryFolder$|^exitRule$|^synchronizedTestRule$|^clearDatabaseRule.*$|^configurationRule$"/>
        </module>
        <module name="ArrayTypeStyle"/>
        <module name="UpperEll"/>
    </module>
    <module name="Translation"/>
    <module name="FileLength"/>
    <module name="SuppressionCommentFilter"/>
    <module name="SuppressionCommentFilter">
        <property name="offCommentFormat" value="CHECKSTYLE\:(\w+)\:OFF"/>
        <property name="onCommentFormat" value="CHECKSTYLE\:(\w+)\:ON"/>
        <property name="checkFormat" value="$1"/>
    </module>
</module>
```

Comment: Might be a problem with your XML. Can you show it to us?

Comment: Sure, I added the XML to my question. But it seems that there is additional step necessary to use the rules. _Settings_ -> _QAPlug_ -> _Coding Rules_. Now right click on desired profile and select _Import_ from context menu. Then point to checkstyle configuration XML file and they are going to be imported. I must say that it's hidden really nice. I wouldn't have found that probably without help of a team mate.

Comment: Ah good, so the problem is solved?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IntelliJ IDEA code format from checkstyle configuration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14539313/intellij-idea-code-format-from-checkstyle-configuration)