# NoLineWrap in checkstyle.xml in IntelliJ for Java does not work as expected

Tags: java, intellij-idea, checkstyle

I try to recreate the default code style from IntelliJ to a checkstyle.xml file. As mentioned here [Use IntelliJ code style in Checkstyle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32371967/use-intellij-code-style-in-checkstyle) there is no quick option so I try to rebuild it step by step. I'm quite close but I struggle with the settings for line wrapping. As there is the option `NoLineWrap` from checkstyle the lines got cut nevertheless. Also, a look in the settings proves that the statements were ignored. As you can see in the screenshot there is still 'wrap if long' for many options although I added the following to the XML file:

```
 <module name="NoLineWrap">
            <property name="tokens"
                      value="PACKAGE_DEF, IMPORT, STATIC_IMPORT, ENUM_DEF, CLASS_DEF , METHOD_DEF , INTERFACE_DEF, COMPACT_CTOR_DEF"/>
 </module>
```

[image: Settings IntelliJ own style sheet]

Can somebody help me with my problem?

---

*Edit:* My complete checkstyle.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC
    "-//Checkstyle//DTD Checkstyle Configuration 1.3//EN"
    "https://checkstyle.org/dtds/configuration_1_3.dtd">
<module name="Checker">
<module name="SuppressWarningsFilter"/>

<property name="charset" value="UTF-8"/>

<property name="severity" value="warning"/>

<property name="fileExtensions" value="java, properties, xml"/>
<!-- Excludes all 'module-info.java' files              -->
<!-- See https://checkstyle.org/filefilters/index.html -->
<module name="BeforeExecutionExclusionFileFilter">
    <property name="fileNamePattern" value="module\-info\.java$"/>
</module>
<!-- https://checkstyle.org/filters/suppressionfilter.html -->
<module name="SuppressionFilter">
    <property name="file" value="${org.checkstyle.google.suppressionfilter.config}"
              default="checkstyle-suppressions.xml"/>
    <property name="optional" value="true"/>
</module>

<!-- Checks for whitespace                               -->
<!-- See http://checkstyle.org/checks/whitespace/index.html -->
<module name="FileTabCharacter">
    <property name="eachLine" value="true"/>
</module>

<module name="LineLength">
    <property name="fileExtensions" value="java"/>
    <property name="max" value="120"/>
    <property name="ignorePattern" value="^package.*|^import.*|a href|href|http://|https://|ftp://"/>
</module>

<module name="TreeWalker">
    <module name="OuterTypeFilename"/>
    <module name="IllegalTokenText">
        <property name="tokens" value="STRING_LITERAL, CHAR_LITERAL"/>
        <property name="format"
                  value="\\u00(09|0(a|A)|0(c|C)|0(d|D)|22|27|5(C|c))|\\(0(10|11|12|14|15|42|47)|134)"/>
        <property name="message"
                  value="Consider using special escape sequence instead of octal value or Unicode escaped value."/>
    </module>
    <module name="AvoidEscapedUnicodeCharacters">
        <property name="allowEscapesForControlCharacters" value="true"/>
        <property name="allowByTailComment" value="true"/>
        <property name="allowNonPrintableEscapes" value="true"/>
    </module>
    <module name="AvoidStarImport"/>
    <module name="OneTopLevelClass"/>

    <module name="EmptyBlock">
        <property name="option" value="TEXT"/>
        <property name="tokens"
                  value="LITERAL_TRY, LITERAL_FINALLY, LITERAL_IF, LITERAL_ELSE, LITERAL_SWITCH"/>
    </module>
    <module name="NeedBraces">
        <property name="tokens"
                  value="LITERAL_DO, LITERAL_ELSE, LITERAL_FOR, LITERAL_IF, LITERAL_WHILE"/>
    </module>
    <module name="LeftCurly">
        <property name="tokens"
                  value="ANNOTATION_DEF, CLASS_DEF, CTOR_DEF, ENUM_CONSTANT_DEF, ENUM_DEF,
                INTERFACE_DEF, LAMBDA, LITERAL_CASE, LITERAL_CATCH, LITERAL_DEFAULT,
                LITERAL_DO, LITERAL_ELSE, LITERAL_FINALLY, LITERAL_FOR, LITERAL_IF,
                LITERAL_SWITCH, LITERAL_SYNCHRONIZED, LITERAL_TRY, LITERAL_WHILE, METHOD_DEF,
                OBJBLOCK, STATIC_INIT, RECORD_DEF, COMPACT_CTOR_DEF"/>
    </module>
    <module name="RightCurly">
        <property name="id" value="RightCurlySame"/>
        <property name="tokens"
                  value="LITERAL_TRY, LITERAL_CATCH, LITERAL_FINALLY, LITERAL_IF, LITERAL_ELSE,
                LITERAL_DO"/>
    </module>
    <module name="RightCurly">
        <property name="id" value="RightCurlyAlone"/>
        <property name="option" value="alone"/>
        <property name="tokens"
                  value="CLASS_DEF, METHOD_DEF, CTOR_DEF, LITERAL_FOR, LITERAL_WHILE, STATIC_INIT,
                INSTANCE_INIT, ANNOTATION_DEF, ENUM_DEF, INTERFACE_DEF, RECORD_DEF,
                COMPACT_CTOR_DEF, LITERAL_SWITCH"/>
    </module>
    <module name="SuppressionXpathSingleFilter">
        <!-- suppresion is required till https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/issues/7541 -->
        <property name="id" value="RightCurlyAlone"/>
        <property name="query" value="//RCURLY[parent::SLIST[count(./*)=1]
                                 or preceding-sibling::*[last()][self::LCURLY]]"/>
    </module>
    <module name="WhitespaceAfter">
        <property name="tokens"
                  value="COMMA, SEMI, TYPECAST, LITERAL_IF, LITERAL_ELSE, LITERAL_RETURN,
                LITERAL_WHILE, LITERAL_DO, LITERAL_FOR, LITERAL_FINALLY, DO_WHILE, ELLIPSIS,
                LITERAL_SWITCH, LITERAL_SYNCHRONIZED, LITERAL_TRY, LITERAL_CATCH, LAMBDA,
                LITERAL_YIELD, LITERAL_CASE"/>
    </module>
    <module name="WhitespaceAround">
        <property name="allowEmptyConstructors" value="true"/>
        <property name="allowEmptyLambdas" value="true"/>
        <property name="allowEmptyMethods" value="true"/>
        <property name="allowEmptyTypes" value="true"/>
        <property name="allowEmptyLoops" value="true"/>
        <property name="ignoreEnhancedForColon" value="false"/>
        <property name="tokens"
                  value="ASSIGN, BAND, BAND_ASSIGN, BOR, BOR_ASSIGN, BSR, BSR_ASSIGN, BXOR,
                BXOR_ASSIGN, COLON, DIV, DIV_ASSIGN, DO_WHILE, EQUAL, GE, GT, LAMBDA, LAND,
                LCURLY, LE, LITERAL_CATCH, LITERAL_DO, LITERAL_ELSE, LITERAL_FINALLY,
                LITERAL_FOR, LITERAL_IF, LITERAL_RETURN, LITERAL_SWITCH, LITERAL_SYNCHRONIZED,
                LITERAL_TRY, LITERAL_WHILE, LOR, LT, MINUS, MINUS_ASSIGN, MOD, MOD_ASSIGN,
                NOT_EQUAL, PLUS, PLUS_ASSIGN, QUESTION, RCURLY, SL, SLIST, SL_ASSIGN, SR,
                SR_ASSIGN, STAR, STAR_ASSIGN, LITERAL_ASSERT, TYPE_EXTENSION_AND"/>
        <message key="ws.notFollowed"
                 value="WhitespaceAround: ''{0}'' is not followed by whitespace. Empty blocks
           may only be represented as '{}' when not part of a multi-block statement (4.1.3)"/>
        <message key="ws.notPreceded"
                 value="WhitespaceAround: ''{0}'' is not preceded with whitespace."/>
    </module>
    <module name="OneStatementPerLine"/>
    <module name="MultipleVariableDeclarations"/>
    <module name="ArrayTypeStyle"/>
    <module name="MissingSwitchDefault"/>
    <module name="FallThrough"/>
    <module name="UpperEll"/>
    <module name="ModifierOrder"/>
    <module name="EmptyLineSeparator">
        <property name="tokens"
                  value="PACKAGE_DEF, IMPORT, STATIC_IMPORT, CLASS_DEF, INTERFACE_DEF, ENUM_DEF,
                STATIC_INIT, INSTANCE_INIT, METHOD_DEF, CTOR_DEF, VARIABLE_DEF, RECORD_DEF,
                COMPACT_CTOR_DEF"/>
        <property name="allowNoEmptyLineBetweenFields" value="true"/>
    </module>
    <module name="SeparatorWrap">
        <property name="id" value="SeparatorWrapDot"/>
        <property name="tokens" value="DOT"/>
        <property name="option" value="nl"/>
    </module>
    <module name="SeparatorWrap">
        <property name="id" value="SeparatorWrapComma"/>
        <property name="tokens" value="COMMA"/>
        <property name="option" value="EOL"/>
    </module>
    <module name="SeparatorWrap">
        <!-- ELLIPSIS is EOL until https://github.com/google/styleguide/issues/259 -->
        <property name="id" value="SeparatorWrapEllipsis"/>
        <property name="tokens" value="ELLIPSIS"/>
        <property name="option" value="EOL"/>
    </module>
    <module name="SeparatorWrap">
        <!-- ARRAY_DECLARATOR is EOL until https://github.com/google/styleguide/issues/258 -->
        <property name="id" value="SeparatorWrapArrayDeclarator"/>
        <property name="tokens" value="ARRAY_DECLARATOR"/>
        <property name="option" value="EOL"/>
    </module>
    <module name="SeparatorWrap">
        <property name="id" value="SeparatorWrapMethodRef"/>
        <property name="tokens" value="METHOD_REF"/>
        <property name="option" value="nl"/>
    </module>
    <module name="PackageName">
        <property name="format" value="^[a-z]+(\.[a-z][a-z0-9]*)*$"/>
        <message key="name.invalidPattern"
                 value="Package name ''{0}'' must match pattern ''{1}''."/>
    </module>
    <module name="TypeName">
        <property name="tokens" value="CLASS_DEF, INTERFACE_DEF, ENUM_DEF,
                ANNOTATION_DEF, RECORD_DEF"/>
        <message key="name.invalidPattern"
                 value="Type name ''{0}'' must match pattern ''{1}''."/>
    </module>
    <module name="MemberName">
        <property name="format" value="^[a-z][a-z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]*$"/>
        <message key="name.invalidPattern"
                 value="Member name ''{0}'' must match pattern ''{1}''."/>
    </module>
    <module name="ParameterName">
        <property name="format" value="^[a-z]([a-z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]*)?$"/>
        <message key="name.invalidPattern"
                 value="Parameter name ''{0}'' must match pattern ''{1}''."/>
    </module>
    <module name="LambdaParameterName">
        <property name="format" value="^[a-z]([a-z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]*)?$"/>
        <message key="name.invalidPattern"
                 value="Lambda parameter name ''{0}'' must match pattern ''{1}''."/>
    </module>
    <module name="CatchParameterName">
        <property name="format" value="^[a-z]([a-z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]*)?$"/>
        <message key="name.invalidPattern"
                 value="Catch parameter name ''{0}'' must match pattern ''{1}''."/>
    </module>
    <module name="LocalVariableName">
        <property name="format" value="^[a-z]([a-z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]*)?$"/>
        <message key="name.invalidPattern"
                 value="Local variable name ''{0}'' must match pattern ''{1}''."/>
    </module>
    <module name="PatternVariableName">
        <property name="format" value="^[a-z]([a-z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]*)?$"/>
        <message key="name.invalidPattern"
                 value="Pattern variable name ''{0}'' must match pattern ''{1}''."/>
    </module>
    <module name="ClassTypeParameterName">
        <property name="format" value="(^[A-Z][0-9]?)$|([A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*[T]$)"/>
        <message key="name.invalidPattern"
                 value="Class type name ''{0}'' must match pattern ''{1}''."/>
    </module>
    <module name="RecordComponentName">
        <property name="format" value="^[a-z]([a-z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]*)?$"/>
        <message key="name.invalidPattern"
                 value="Record component name ''{0}'' must match pattern ''{1}''."/>
    </module>
    <module name="RecordTypeParameterName">
        <property name="format" value="(^[A-Z][0-9]?)$|([A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*[T]$)"/>
        <message key="name.invalidPattern"
                 value="Record type name ''{0}'' must match pattern ''{1}''."/>
    </module>
    <module name="MethodTypeParameterName">
        <property name="format" value="(^[A-Z][0-9]?)$|([A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*[T]$)"/>
        <message key="name.invalidPattern"
                 value="Method type name ''{0}'' must match pattern ''{1}''."/>
    </module>
    <module name="InterfaceTypeParameterName">
        <property name="format" value="(^[A-Z][0-9]?)$|([A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*[T]$)"/>
        <message key="name.invalidPattern"
                 value="Interface type name ''{0}'' must match pattern ''{1}''."/>
    </module>
    <module name="NoFinalizer"/>
    <module name="GenericWhitespace">
        <message key="ws.followed"
                 value="GenericWhitespace ''{0}'' is followed by whitespace."/>
        <message key="ws.preceded"
                 value="GenericWhitespace ''{0}'' is preceded with whitespace."/>
        <message key="ws.illegalFollow"
                 value="GenericWhitespace ''{0}'' should followed by whitespace."/>
        <message key="ws.notPreceded"
                 value="GenericWhitespace ''{0}'' is not preceded with whitespace."/>
    </module>
    <module name="Indentation">
        <property name="tabWidth" value="4"/>
        <property name="basicOffset" value="4"/>
        <property name="braceAdjustment" value="4"/>
        <property name="caseIndent" value="8"/>
        <property name="throwsIndent" value="0"/>
        <property name="lineWrappingIndentation" value="8"/>
        <property name="arrayInitIndent" value="4"/>
    </module>
    <module name="AbbreviationAsWordInName">
        <property name="ignoreFinal" value="false"/>
        <property name="allowedAbbreviationLength" value="0"/>
        <property name="tokens"
                  value="CLASS_DEF, INTERFACE_DEF, ENUM_DEF, ANNOTATION_DEF, ANNOTATION_FIELD_DEF,
                PARAMETER_DEF, VARIABLE_DEF, METHOD_DEF, PATTERN_VARIABLE_DEF, RECORD_DEF,
                RECORD_COMPONENT_DEF"/>
    </module>
    <module name="NoWhitespaceBeforeCaseDefaultColon"/>
    <module name="OverloadMethodsDeclarationOrder"/>
    <module name="VariableDeclarationUsageDistance"/>
    <module name="CustomImportOrder">
        <property name="sortImportsInGroupAlphabetically" value="true"/>
        <property name="separateLineBetweenGroups" value="true"/>
        <property name="customImportOrderRules" value="STATIC###THIRD_PARTY_PACKAGE"/>
        <property name="tokens" value="IMPORT, STATIC_IMPORT, PACKAGE_DEF"/>
    </module>
    <module name="MethodParamPad">
        <property name="tokens"
                  value="CTOR_DEF, LITERAL_NEW, METHOD_CALL, METHOD_DEF,
                SUPER_CTOR_CALL, ENUM_CONSTANT_DEF, RECORD_DEF"/>
    </module>
    <module name="NoWhitespaceBefore">
        <property name="tokens"
                  value="COMMA, SEMI, POST_INC, POST_DEC, DOT,
                LABELED_STAT, METHOD_REF"/>
        <property name="allowLineBreaks" value="true"/>
    </module>
    <module name="ParenPad">
        <property name="tokens"
                  value="ANNOTATION, ANNOTATION_FIELD_DEF, CTOR_CALL, CTOR_DEF, DOT, ENUM_CONSTANT_DEF,
                EXPR, LITERAL_CATCH, LITERAL_DO, LITERAL_FOR, LITERAL_IF, LITERAL_NEW,
                LITERAL_SWITCH, LITERAL_SYNCHRONIZED, LITERAL_WHILE, METHOD_CALL,
                METHOD_DEF, QUESTION, RESOURCE_SPECIFICATION, SUPER_CTOR_CALL, LAMBDA,
                RECORD_DEF"/>
    </module>
    <module name="OperatorWrap">
        <property name="option" value="NL"/>
        <property name="tokens"
                  value="BAND, BOR, BSR, BXOR, DIV, EQUAL, GE, GT, LAND, LE, LITERAL_INSTANCEOF, LOR,
                LT, MINUS, MOD, NOT_EQUAL, PLUS, QUESTION, SL, SR, STAR, METHOD_REF,
                TYPE_EXTENSION_AND "/>
    </module>
    <module name="AnnotationLocation">
        <property name="id" value="AnnotationLocationMostCases"/>
        <property name="tokens"
                  value="CLASS_DEF, INTERFACE_DEF, ENUM_DEF, METHOD_DEF, CTOR_DEF,
                  RECORD_DEF, COMPACT_CTOR_DEF"/>
    </module>
    <module name="AnnotationLocation">
        <property name="id" value="AnnotationLocationVariables"/>
        <property name="tokens" value="VARIABLE_DEF"/>
        <property name="allowSamelineMultipleAnnotations" value="true"/>
    </module>
    <module name="NonEmptyAtclauseDescription"/>
    <module name="InvalidJavadocPosition"/>
    <module name="JavadocTagContinuationIndentation"/>
    <module name="SummaryJavadoc">
        <property name="forbiddenSummaryFragments"
                  value="^@return the *|^This method returns |^A [{]@code [a-zA-Z0-9]+[}]( is a )"/>
    </module>
    <module name="JavadocParagraph"/>
    <module name="RequireEmptyLineBeforeBlockTagGroup"/>
    <module name="AtclauseOrder">
        <property name="tagOrder" value="@param, @return, @throws, @deprecated"/>
        <property name="target"
                  value="CLASS_DEF, INTERFACE_DEF, ENUM_DEF, METHOD_DEF, CTOR_DEF, VARIABLE_DEF"/>
    </module>
    <module name="JavadocMethod">
        <property name="accessModifiers" value="public"/>
        <property name="allowMissingParamTags" value="true"/>
        <property name="allowMissingReturnTag" value="true"/>
        <property name="allowedAnnotations" value="Override, Test"/>
        <property name="tokens" value="METHOD_DEF, CTOR_DEF, ANNOTATION_FIELD_DEF, COMPACT_CTOR_DEF"/>
    </module>
    <module name="MethodName">
        <property name="format" value="^[a-z][a-z0-9]\w*$"/>
        <message key="name.invalidPattern"
                 value="Method name ''{0}'' must match pattern ''{1}''."/>
    </module>
    <module name="SingleLineJavadoc"/>
    <module name="EmptyCatchBlock">
        <property name="exceptionVariableName" value="expected"/>
    </module>
    <module name="CommentsIndentation">
        <property name="tokens" value="SINGLE_LINE_COMMENT, BLOCK_COMMENT_BEGIN"/>
    </module>
    <!-- https://checkstyle.org/filters/suppressionxpathfilter.html -->
    <module name="SuppressionXpathFilter">
        <property name="file" value="${org.checkstyle.google.suppressionxpathfilter.config}"
                  default="checkstyle-xpath-suppressions.xml"/>
        <property name="optional" value="true"/>
    </module>
    <module name="SuppressWarningsHolder"/>
    <module name="SuppressionCommentFilter">
        <property name="offCommentFormat" value="CHECKSTYLE.OFF\: ([\w\|]+)"/>
        <property name="onCommentFormat" value="CHECKSTYLE.ON\: ([\w\|]+)"/>
        <property name="checkFormat" value="$1"/>
    </module>
    <module name="SuppressWithNearbyCommentFilter">
        <property name="commentFormat" value="CHECKSTYLE.SUPPRESS\: ([\w\|]+)"/>
        <!-- $1 refers to the first match group in the regex defined in commentFormat -->
        <property name="checkFormat" value="$1"/>
        <!-- The check is suppressed in the next line of code after the comment -->
        <property name="influenceFormat" value="1"/>
    </module>
    <module name="NoLineWrap">
        <property name="tokens"
                  value="PACKAGE_DEF, IMPORT, STATIC_IMPORT, ENUM_DEF, CLASS_DEF , METHOD_DEF , INTERFACE_DEF, COMPACT_CTOR_DEF"/>
    </module>
</module>
```

Comment: Could you please share xml with code style that you importing?