# Intellij code format defaults for checkstyle

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide, code-formatting, checkstyle

I enjoy clean, consistent code. I think teams should enforce this on their code bases.

However, I want to spend 0 time fudging around with alphabetizing my imports, messing with tab/space characters, and other unpleasantries like that.

I use an IDE (Intellij) with a great auto formatter. It will even re-arrange imports, etc.

I have checkstyle up and running, and I would like to be able to just enforce the code style that results when I autoformat in intellij. Thus the rule of the land all team members will be "just do the autoformat and you good"

Is there a checkstyle.xml out there that meets this requirement? Or a way to achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate, please see [IntelliJ IDEA code format from checkstyle configuration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14539313/intellij-idea-code-format-from-checkstyle-configuration)

Comment: This is not a duplicate. It's IntelliJ -> checkstyle not checkstyle-> IntelliJ

Comment: Not possible currently. You may [request it](https://github.com/jshiell/checkstyle-idea/issues) as a new feature.

Answer (score 1):

There is no tool, so I took [google's](https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/blob/master/src/main/resources/google_checks.xml) and started tweaking it.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC
        "-//Puppy Crawl//DTD Check Configuration 1.3//EN"
        "http://www.puppycrawl.com/dtds/configuration_1_3.dtd">

<!--
  originally from Google checkstyle https://raw.githubusercontent.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/master/src/main/resources/google_checks.xml
 -->

<module name="Checker">
    <property name="charset" value="UTF-8"/>

    <property name="severity" value="error"/>

    <property name="fileExtensions" value="java, properties, xml"/>
    <!-- Checks for whitespace                               -->
    <!-- See http://checkstyle.sf.net/config_whitespace.html -->
    <module name="FileTabCharacter">
        <property name="eachLine" value="true"/>
    </module>

    <module name="TreeWalker">
        <module name="OuterTypeFilename"/>
        <module name="IllegalTokenText">
            <property name="tokens" value="STRING_LITERAL, CHAR_LITERAL"/>
            <property name="format"
                      value="\\u00(08|09|0(a|A)|0(c|C)|0(d|D)|22|27|5(C|c))|\\(0(10|11|12|14|15|42|47)|134)"/>
            <property name="message" value="Avoid using corresponding octal or Unicode escape."/>
        </module>
        <module name="AvoidEscapedUnicodeCharacters">
            <property name="allowEscapesForControlCharacters" value="true"/>
            <property name="allowByTailComment" value="true"/>
            <property name="allowNonPrintableEscapes" value="true"/>
        </module>
        <module name="LineLength">
            <property name="max" value="120"/>
            <property name="ignorePattern" value="^package.*|^import.*|a href|href|http://|https://|ftp://"/>
        </module>
        <module name="OneTopLevelClass"/>
        <module name="NoLineWrap"/>
        <module name="EmptyBlock">
            <property name="option" value="TEXT"/>
            <property name="tokens" value="LITERAL_TRY, LITERAL_FINALLY, LITERAL_IF, LITERAL_ELSE, LITERAL_SWITCH"/>
        </module>
        <module name="NeedBraces"/>
        <module name="LeftCurly">
            <property name="maxLineLength" value="100"/>
        </module>
        <module name="RightCurly">
            <property name="id" value="RightCurlySame"/>
            <property name="tokens"
                      value="LITERAL_TRY, LITERAL_CATCH, LITERAL_FINALLY, LITERAL_IF, LITERAL_ELSE, LITERAL_DO"/>
        </module>
        <module name="RightCurly">
            <property name="id" value="RightCurlyAlone"/>
            <property name="option" value="alone"/>
            <property name="tokens"
                      value="CLASS_DEF, METHOD_DEF, CTOR_DEF, LITERAL_FOR, LITERAL_WHILE, STATIC_INIT, INSTANCE_INIT"/>
        </module>
        <module name="WhitespaceAround">
            <property name="allowEmptyConstructors" value="true"/>
            <property name="allowEmptyMethods" value="true"/>
            <property name="allowEmptyTypes" value="true"/>
            <property name="allowEmptyLoops" value="true"/>
            <message key="ws.notFollowed"
                     value="WhitespaceAround: ''{0}'' is not followed by whitespace. Empty blocks may only be represented as '{}' when not part of a multi-block statement (4.1.3)"/>
            <message key="ws.notPreceded"
                     value="WhitespaceAround: ''{0}'' is not preceded with whitespace."/>
        </module>
        <module name="OneStatementPerLine"/>
        <module name="MultipleVariableDeclarations"/>
        <module name="ArrayTypeStyle"/>
        <module name="MissingSwitchDefault"/>
        <module name="FallThrough"/>
        <module name="UpperEll"/>
        <module name="ModifierOrder"/>
        <module name="EmptyLineSeparator">
            <property name="allowNoEmptyLineBetweenFields" value="true"/>
        </module>
        <module name="SeparatorWrap">
            <property name="id" value="SeparatorWrapDot"/>
            <property name="tokens" value="DOT"/>
            <property name="option" value="nl"/>
        </module>
        <module name="SeparatorWrap">
            <property name="id" value="SeparatorWrapComma"/>
            <property name="tokens" value="COMMA"/>
            <property name="option" value="EOL"/>
        </module>
        <module name="PackageName">
            <property name="format" value="^[a-z]+(\.[a-z][a-z0-9]*)*$"/>
            <message key="name.invalidPattern"
                     value="Package name ''{0}'' must match pattern ''{1}''."/>
        </module>
        <module name="TypeName">
            <message key="name.invalidPattern"
                     value="Type name ''{0}'' must match pattern ''{1}''."/>
        </module>
        <module name="MemberName">
            <property name="format" value="^[a-z][a-z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]*$"/>
            <message key="name.invalidPattern"
                     value="Member name ''{0}'' must match pattern ''{1}''."/>
        </module>
        <module name="ParameterName">
            <property name="id" value="ParameterNameNonPublic"/>
            <property name="format" value="^[a-z]([a-z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]*)?$"/>
            <property name="excludeScope" value="public"/>
            <message key="name.invalidPattern"
                     value="Parameter name ''{0}'' must match pattern ''{1}''."/>
        </module>
        <module name="ParameterName">
            <property name="id" value="ParameterNamePublic"/>
            <property name="format" value="^[a-z][a-z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]*$"/>
            <property name="scope" value="public"/>
            <message key="name.invalidPattern"
                     value="Parameter name ''{0}'' must match pattern ''{1}''."/>
        </module>
        <module name="CatchParameterName">
            <property name="format" value="^[a-z][a-z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]*$"/>
            <message key="name.invalidPattern"
                     value="Catch parameter name ''{0}'' must match pattern ''{1}''."/>
        </module>
        <module name="LocalVariableName">
            <property name="tokens" value="VARIABLE_DEF"/>
            <property name="format" value="^[a-z][a-z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]*$"/>
            <property name="allowOneCharVarInForLoop" value="true"/>
            <message key="name.invalidPattern"
                     value="Local variable name ''{0}'' must match pattern ''{1}''."/>
        </module>
        <module name="ClassTypeParameterName">
            <property name="format" value="(^[A-Z][0-9]?)$|([A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*[T]$)"/>
            <message key="name.invalidPattern"
                     value="Class type name ''{0}'' must match pattern ''{1}''."/>
        </module>
        <module name="MethodTypeParameterName">
            <property name="format" value="(^[A-Z][0-9]?)$|([A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*[T]$)"/>
            <message key="name.invalidPattern"
                     value="Method type name ''{0}'' must match pattern ''{1}''."/>
        </module>
        <module name="InterfaceTypeParameterName">
            <property name="format" value="(^[A-Z][0-9]?)$|([A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*[T]$)"/>
            <message key="name.invalidPattern"
                     value="Interface type name ''{0}'' must match pattern ''{1}''."/>
        </module>
        <module name="NoFinalizer"/>
        <module name="GenericWhitespace">
            <message key="ws.followed"
                     value="GenericWhitespace ''{0}'' is followed by whitespace."/>
            <message key="ws.preceded"
                     value="GenericWhitespace ''{0}'' is preceded with whitespace."/>
            <message key="ws.illegalFollow"
                     value="GenericWhitespace ''{0}'' should followed by whitespace."/>
            <message key="ws.notPreceded"
                     value="GenericWhitespace ''{0}'' is not preceded with whitespace."/>
        </module>
        <module name="Indentation">
            <property name="basicOffset" value="4"/>
            <property name="braceAdjustment" value="0"/>
            <property name="caseIndent" value="4"/>
            <property name="throwsIndent" value="4"/>
            <property name="lineWrappingIndentation" value="4"/>
            <property name="arrayInitIndent" value="2"/>
        </module>
        <module name="AbbreviationAsWordInName">
            <property name="ignoreFinal" value="false"/>
            <property name="allowedAbbreviationLength" value="1"/>
        </module>
        <module name="OverloadMethodsDeclarationOrder"/>
        <module name="VariableDeclarationUsageDistance"/>
        <module name="CustomImportOrder">
            <property name="sortImportsInGroupAlphabetically" value="true"/>
            <property name="separateLineBetweenGroups" value="true"/>
            <property name="customImportOrderRules" value="THIRD_PARTY_PACKAGE###STANDARD_JAVA_PACKAGE###STATIC"/>
        </module>
        <module name="MethodParamPad"/>
        <module name="ParenPad"/>
        <module name="OperatorWrap">
            <property name="option" value="NL"/>
            <property name="tokens"
                      value="BAND, BOR, BSR, BXOR, DIV, EQUAL, GE, GT, LAND, LE, LITERAL_INSTANCEOF, LOR, LT, MINUS, MOD, NOT_EQUAL, PLUS, QUESTION, SL, SR, STAR, METHOD_REF "/>
        </module>
        <module name="AnnotationLocation">
            <property name="id" value="AnnotationLocationMostCases"/>
            <property name="tokens" value="CLASS_DEF, INTERFACE_DEF, ENUM_DEF, METHOD_DEF, CTOR_DEF"/>
        </module>
        <module name="AnnotationLocation">
            <property name="id" value="AnnotationLocationVariables"/>
            <property name="tokens" value="VARIABLE_DEF"/>
            <property name="allowSamelineMultipleAnnotations" value="true"/>
        </module>
        <module name="NonEmptyAtclauseDescription"/>
        <module name="JavadocTagContinuationIndentation"/>
        <module name="SummaryJavadoc">
            <property name="forbiddenSummaryFragments"
                      value="^@return the *|^This method returns |^A [{]@code [a-zA-Z0-9]+[}]( is a )"/>
        </module>
        <module name="JavadocParagraph"/>
        <module name="AtclauseOrder">
            <property name="tagOrder" value="@param, @return, @throws, @deprecated"/>
            <property name="target" value="CLASS_DEF, INTERFACE_DEF, ENUM_DEF, METHOD_DEF, CTOR_DEF, VARIABLE_DEF"/>
        </module>
        <module name="JavadocMethod">
            <property name="scope" value="nothing"/>
            <property name="allowMissingParamTags" value="true"/>
            <property name="allowMissingThrowsTags" value="true"/>
            <property name="allowMissingReturnTag" value="true"/>
            <property name="minLineCount" value="2"/>
            <property name="allowedAnnotations" value="Override, Test"/>
            <property name="allowThrowsTagsForSubclasses" value="true"/>
        </module>
        <module name="MethodName">
            <property name="format" value="^[a-z][a-z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_]*$"/>
            <message key="name.invalidPattern"
                     value="Method name ''{0}'' must match pattern ''{1}''."/>
        </module>
        <module name="SingleLineJavadoc">
            <property name="ignoreInlineTags" value="false"/>
        </module>
        <module name="EmptyCatchBlock">
            <property name="exceptionVariableName" value="expected"/>
        </module>
        <module name="CommentsIndentation"/>
    </module>
</module>
```

Comment: `org.infernus.idea.checkstyle.exception.CheckStylePluginException`: The Checkstyle rules file could not be parsed. cannot initialize module TreeWalker - Property 'maxLineLength' in module LeftCurly does not exist, please check the documentation