# IntelliJ IDEA code reformat not working

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, checkstyle

I am using IntelliJ IDEA version 2017.3, then I install plug-in CheckStyle-IDEA v 5.16.0 successful, I install *Apache Maven Checkstyle Plugin* to run `myCheckFile.xml`. At `install` phase, I received many check style error like:

```
Indentation: '.' has incorrect indentation level 6, expected level should be 8.
Indentation: 'new' has incorrect indentation level 6, expected level should be 8.
```

After importing CheckStyle [settings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35273850/2062384), I expect when I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> inside IntelliJ IDEA all check style error will die but that doesn't happen, is there's something i'm missing ?

Comment: checkstyle is not combined with the formatter.  You need to tell the formatter explicitly what to do.

Comment: Could you please share your checkstyle scheme? May be not all settings are supported by IDEA formatter.

Comment: If you install Save Actions plugin and configure it to reformat on save then it'll automatically format for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have a .editorconfig file which is taking precedence. I ran into the same problem and my solution was to comment out the .editorconfig file. Our team is using JHipster, which automatically generates a .editorconfig file. This generally has just a few key settings, including indent_size=4. I was experimenting with Google's checkstyle xml settings and saw the same overall issue you were seeing, where the checkstyle plugin was indicating the indentation was wrong, but the code/reformat option wasn't fixing it.

TL;DR - see if you have a .editorconfig file and if so delete it or comment out the conflicting styles.

Comment: Where is this file located?

Comment: There is also a checkbox 'Enable EditorConfig support' under Preferences->Editor->Code Style that you can disable to prevent a .editorconfig file from overriding settings.