# How to get (IntelliJ + checkstyle code formatting) working?

Tags: intellij-idea, checkstyle, intellij-plugin

I followed the instructions in this response: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35273850/1122470

However, after using the automatic formatting <kbd>`Ctrl`</kbd><kbd>`Shift`</kbd><kbd>`Alt`</kbd><kbd>`L`</kbd>, the code was reformatted for sure, yes, but I am not sure if it was according to the checkstyle.xml

When I try to check for violations using `gradlew checkstyle` all the previous errors seem to remain.

Any suggestions on how to get the formatting done according to the checkstyle rules using the plugin?

Edit: adding config screenshots

[image]

[image: Codestyle settings]

Comment: are both (idea and gradle) using the same checkstyle config?

Comment: yes! both are using the same config file

Comment: Try to press `ctrl+shift+a` and type `checkstyle` - there should be actions related to checkstyle plugin.

Comment: So have you imported checkstyle config and doesn't see it is applied? (latest IDEA import location: https://duaw26jehqd4r.cloudfront.net/items/263S3o3U0m1J2f3z200k/Image%202018-10-27%20at%2011.41.17.png?v=cdfc6738).

You should set the rule which will say for sure, was it applied or not, as you're not sure it works.

Comment: @extempl Please check the updated question (I added the screenshots) and please confirm if that is what you meant! If so, I have applied the configurations

Comment: Try to import checkstyle configuration from the `Code Style -> Java` page. As you're importing it globally, so it may be overridden by local (Java) rules.

Comment: Also after importing make sure the imported scheme is selected in the `Scheme` dropdown beside the gear wheel icon. As of the first screenshot - it looks like it is only for checking, not formatting.

Comment: The same configuration is applied under `Code Style -> Java` page and it is the selected scheme. 
Example of a specific problem: organize imports isn't moving the code around.