# Importing checkstyle suppressions for IntelliJ code style

Tags: intellij-idea, code-formatting, checkstyle, maven-checkstyle-plugin

Mostly just out of curiosity, but if you are using a checkstyle configuration file `checkstyle.xml` and a (separate) suppression file `checkstyle-suppressions.xml` with the `maven-checkstyle-plugin` on a maven project, and you'd like to import those checkstyle configurations into a **code style** in IntelliJ by using the CheckStyle-IDEA plugin, you can do so (see, for example, [IntelliJ IDEA code format from checkstyle configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14539313/intellij-idea-code-format-from-checkstyle-configuration)) - but what about the suppressions for this code style? In setting your code style in IntelliJ, you can only import configurations from one file (certainly the `checkstyle.xml`). Does this code style then 'know' about the suppressions if they are specified correctly in your `pom.xml` using, say, the `<suppressionsLocation>` tag? Does it need to know about the suppressions?

Comment: Hi! Not sure that it's supported. You may ask the plugin developers though: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/1065-checkstyle-idea