# Is there a quick way to refactor the entire codebase to adopt a different code convention?

Tags: java, checkstyle

I have received ownership of a code base that, although very well written, uses a rather bizarre convention:

```
public void someMethod(String pName, Integer pAge, Context pContext) 
{ 
    ... 
}
```

I'd like to make the following two changes to the entire code:

```
public void someMethod(String name, Integer age, Context context) { ... }
```

1. Opening bracket in the same line of the method declaration
2. Use a camelCase name for all parameters of the method, without this weird "p" prefix

Can checkstyle help me here? I'm looking but I can't find a way to rename all parameters in all method signatures to something more pleasant.

Comment: If you are using an IDE like Eclipse, you can auto-format the code based on a coding convention you have specified. I don't know if you can achieve this for the parameters' name convention though.

Comment: Just a side note: the 'weird "p" prefix' looks like [Hungarian notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation). The original programmer was probably trained to use that (probably with C/C++) and is trying to apply it to Java.

Comment: @Ted I don't think this is Hungarian notiation. The prefix 'p' seems to be used to easily identify method parameters, compared to class members, or other variables declared at the method level.

Comment: Eclipse can do a lot work for you have a look at: http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-menu-refactor.htm

I think "Inline" will resolve the bracket issue and with "Change Method Signature" or "Rename" you can change the parameter names

Comment: @Laf - You may be right. My guess was that the "p" stands for "pointer", because all the arguments are objects. (Also, OP originally had `iAge` for the second parameter, which affected my perception of what's going on.)

Comment: @Ted Oh, I had assumed he'd have used 'n' for the `Integer` parameter, but you are right, those are objects, I missed this point ;)

Comment: @Ted, exactly, that's why I edited for clarity; it's not hungarian (which I wouldn't want to keep anyway), it's... something else :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are willing to use the eclipse IDE it'd offer a very handy feature for auto-formatting code:

http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fpreferences%2Fjava%2Fcodestyle%2Fref-preferences-formatter.htm

It is pretty self-explanatory and straight-forward in my opinion.

---

Eclipse allows for regex based **search and replace** operations.

Just open ***Search > File...*** there enter the following regex for ***Containing text:***

```
\b[p]([A-Z][a-z]+)\b
```

And tick both ***Case sensitive*** and ***Regular expression***.
Then press ***Replace...***

In the newly popped up window enter

```
\1
```

in the *With:* field and tick *Regular expression*.

*Edit:* Sadly in its current version Eclipse does not support the **\L** flag for content groups so you are still stuck with an uppercase leading letter.

---

To answer your question about checkstyle: No, checkstyle is a tool used for analyzing code not for changing.

[Using checkstyle to format code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12872283/using-checkstyle-to-format-code)
(Question from Oct'12)

---

Also did some research, here's another stackoverflow question aiming at the practically same. The solution offered there is similarly work intensive.

[Can I automatically refactor an entire java project and rename uppercase method parameters to lowercase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838967/can-i-automatically-refactor-an-entire-java-project-and-rename-uppercase-method)
(Question from Oct'10)

Comment: I thought it could do the refactoring of the parameters too; but it is similar to NetBeans. I'll have to do it by hand, class by class...

Comment: Well that sadly is a limitation of the auto-formatting. It only formats code.

Comment: I added a regex that does the replacement for you. Check the edited answer.